# Iteration times for gradient descent (GD) and stochastic gradient descent (SGD)

Tags: machine-learning, iteration, complexity-theory, gradient-descent

I'm curious about the computational complexity between gradient descent (GD) and stochastic gradient descent (SGD) which was mentioned in this [paper](https://leon.bottou.org/publications/pdf/compstat-2010.pdf)

I found an easier version [lecture notes](https://stanford.edu/~rezab/classes/cme323/S15/notes/lec11.pdf) which says if we want to reach accuracy of $$ e $$, then

- the iteration number in GD will be O(log(1/e))
- the iteration number in SGD will be O(1/e)

How to obtain these two iteration number? Thank you!

Comment: here, you should find what you are looking for here (sorry for  not writting it down)
https://github.com/Frayal/M2-DataScience/tree/master/optmization%20for%20data%20science